# Show line numbers in monitor stack traces in JProfiler

Tags: java, jprofiler

I am using JProfiler to debug some lock contention problems. I can see the problematic blocked lock usages in the monitor history, and can see the filtered stack trace for waiting thread and owning thread. However, the stack trace doesn't display any line information. Is there a way to get these backtraces?

Answer (score 5):

In the profiling settings you can switch on line number resolution:

[image]

Note that the line number on a node always refers to the class in the parent node.